# argument of type 'elementfinder' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to make function if check box is not checked then click on it when I call this function I am getting error message 
"argument of type 'elementfinder' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'"

//variable

```
md5hash_checkbox = element(by.id('md5hash'));
 //To check check box if not selected
  selectCheckBox(checkValue: boolean){
        this.checkValue.isSelected().then(selected => {
            if (selected) {
                console.log(checkValue+': Is Already selected');
            } else {
                this.checkValue.click();
            }
        });
```

on calling function like this.selectCheckBox(this.sha1hash_checkbox);
Getting error message "argument of type 'elementfinder' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'"

Answer (score 1):

`isSelected()` is applicable to `ElementFinder` not `boolean`.
You should do this:

```
selectCheckbox(): void {
  el:ElementFinder =  element(by.id('md5hash'));
  el.isSelected().then(selected => {
    if (selected) {
        console.log(el + ': Is Already selected');
    } else {
        el.click();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`selectCheckBox()` expects to accept a web element, thus you should declare the argument type to `ElementFinder`, rather than `boolean`.  It should be like:

```
selectCheckBox(targetElement: ElementFinder) {
  // only when check box is not selected, then click it
  targetElement.isSelected().then(selected => {
    if (selected) {
      console.log('Already selected');
    } else {
      targetElement.click();
    }
  });
}


md5hash_checkbox = element(by.id('md5hash'));;
selectCheckBox(md5hash_checkbox);
```